# Centos7でのパケットキャプチャの注意点

Tags: centos, vmware

CentOS7をVMwareのESXi上に建てました。そして仮想SWから来たパケット（通常のアップリンクへの通信経路ではなく、ミラーリング設定として管理者に作成してもらった経路を通ってきたもの）をCentOS7でパケットキャプチャしようとしてもうまく行きません。

自分が出しているDHCPパケットとかはミラーリング出来ていますが、それ以外が出来ません。
CentOS7でパケットキャプチャをするときの注意点として、

1. 該当ポートはプロミスキャスモードにする。
2. firewalldはシャットダウンしておく。

以外に何かありますでしょうか。思いつくものを教えてください。

Comment: パケットキャプチャは具体的にどんな方法で行っていますか？

Comment: パケットキャプチャは2パターンを試しています。一つはwiresharkのLinux版を使用しているケース。もう一つはtcpdump -i と-vを使っていますが両方とも同じようなものしか取れていません。なので、Centos7に問題があるのかと。

Comment: 質問に直接関わる内容は、コメントでは無く本文に追記してもらった方が(質問一覧のトップに再び上がって)目に留まりやすくなります。

Comment: あてずっぽうですが、ESXi で何かする必要があるかもしれません。https://docs.vmware.com/jp/VMware-vSphere/6.5/com.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc/GUID-CFFD9157-FC17-440D-BDB4-E16FD447A1BA.html